# get element by Id and addClass in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, class, getelementbyid

m trying to get a element by its Id in angularJs and then add a class to it. I have used "*ng-attr-id*" to assign id to my element and now m not able to addClass to it.

html:

```
<div ng-attr-id= {{id}} >Text</div>
<button ng-click="action">action</button>
```

script:

```
  $scope.id="name";

  $scope.action=function(){
  angular.element($document[0].getElementById("name")).addClass("align");
  }
```

the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/VjORCl5xoHQZbzBG6HDp?p=preview

PS :Any solution other than using ng-class will be more appreciated. I dont need that based on my current problem

Comment: Reason is simple, controller runs before the dom can be compiled. You don't put dom manipulation code in a controller. Try using `ng-class` bound to a scope variable

Comment: @charlietfl ive tried using ng-class, but dont need it right now. where else can i put my dom manipulation code. actually m assigning the "id" to an element in a link function in a directive. So, before the assignment of id, my controller gets executed and m not able to get the result.

Comment: why aren't you using the directive for the class change code? WHat specifically is the problem that doesn't let you use `ng-class`? Seems you are fixated on using element ID which is hardly ever used in agular

Comment: i want to apply those classes to multiple elements which are in ng-repeat. so the class gets applied to all elements. so.. i need to assign ids to elements

Comment: not in angular you don't...nobody uses ID for doing that in angular, they use ng-class. Set an active item in scope and use ng-class to compare current item in repeat to that active item

Answer (score 4):

By Making a couple minor changes, your code will work. Although my preference is generally to use `ng-class` as others have mentioned above.

Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.id="name";

    $scope.action=function(){
      // Angular Element can select by id directly but you just need to add the #
      angular.element('#name').addClass("align");
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!-- id can simply be set but you need the quotes -->
<div id='{{id}}'>Text</div>
<!-- Missing parenthesis on function call -->
<button ng-click="action()">action</button>
```

Check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQav2k5dhVuJxClkTPfG?p=preview)

Comment: i used ur method asok its good. But got an error when used in my  complicated project :Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!.... any more edits or suggestions?

Comment: In your action function, try changing the `angular.element` to `angular.element(document.getElementById($scope.id)).addClass("alllign");` and let me know if that works. The error you are getting is a selector error, meaning what we are passing through `angular.element()` is not working.

Comment: A better alternative would be to use a directive, do you have much experience with those? Generally if it is a one time use I won't use a directive but if I am going to repeat something like what you are doing than I would write a quick little directive for it.

Comment: Still doing DOM manipulation in controller...goes against common best practices.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, which is why I mentioned in the answer I recommend using `ng-class` and in the comment above using a custom directive since the OP says he is not going to use `ng-class`.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you use the ng-class function to manage your class on the elements?

```
<div ng-class="{align: clicked}">Text</div>
<button ng-click="clicked=!clicked">action</button>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.id="name"
        $scope.clicked=false
    })
</script>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GIYbaDnpAugF1ll3fE5C?p=preview

ng-class gets evaluated and where the variables are truthy, those classes get added to the element automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-class would make more sense here rather than using `.addClass` method

```
<div ng-attr-id= {{id}} ng-class="{align: align}">Text</div>
<button ng-click="align=true">action</button>
```